# PHP Split String on Forward Slash Only If It Is Not Preceded By A Backslash

Tags: php, string, parsing, explode

I am making a parser for my [SlashCategory](http://github.com/iandun/SlashCategory), which requires me to split (or tokenize) each string based on the `/` character. I am using PHP's `explode()` function, which works well. For example, it takes the following:

`Book/Title/Lord Of The Flies/Author/William Golding`

And creates an array with:

```
[0] Book
[1] Title
[2] Lord Of The Flies
[3] Author
[4] William Golding
```

However, I have a problem. I do not want `explode()` to break up the string if the forward slash is preceded by a backslash. For example:

`Url/Google/http:\/\/www.google.com`

I want to have an array containing:

```
[0] Url
[1] Google
[2] http://www.google.com
```

Not:

```
[0] Url
[1] Google
[2] http:
[3] 
[4] www.google.com
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: And what syntax would I use to tell it to ignore `\/`?

Comment: use a negative lookbehind

Comment: Okay. So I've got `preg_split("((?<!\\\)/)", $line)`. But when I use something like `something/http:\/\/test`, it will return `http:\/\/test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `preg_split` (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). Example:

```
$input = 'Url/Google/http:\/\/www.google.com';
$output = preg_split('|(?<!\\\)/|', $input); //Yes, thats 3 times a backslash
```

Now, the data in `$output` will still contain your escaped slashes, you'll need to unescape them, like this:

```
$output = preg_split('|(?<!\\\)/|', $input);
array_walk(
    $output,
    function(&$item){
        $item = str_replace('\\/', '/', $item);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ha, I know this has its faults but a one liner could be something like this:

```
<?php
    $s = "Url/Google/http:\/\/www.google.com";
    var_dump (explode('#####',str_replace('\\#####','/',str_replace('/','#####',$s))));
?>
```

Though you would have to find a practical something other than '#####' as you might have a string like that that you may parse.